# Xcode Changing Keyboard

Tags: xcode, ios8, keyboard

I am trying to make a custom keyboard for iOS8. How can I make a button that functions like the default globe on Apple's default keyboard? That way it can change the keyboard. Thank you!

Comment: I am using Objective C by the way.